# Angular7 Parent Component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to set up a security model for my webapp, this security model will have "Panels" (Nodes), Each node will have children, If a top level panel does not have the correct permissions, all children panels should be denied access. The part I'm struggling with right now is getting components from parent elements. It appears once the angular app is compiled, the code no longer knows about actual components? Here is some code, I should be hitting the line that says `this.ParentPanel = e;`, however this never happens as instaceof always returns false.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import { TESTControl } from '../testcontrol/testcontrol.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'test-panel',
  templateUrl: './testpanel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./testpanel.component.scss']
})

export class TESTPanelComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() disabled = false; // when this is disabled, all children will get disabled as well.

  public Children: TESTControl;
  public ParentPanel: any;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.GetParentPanel();
  }

  constructor(public element: ElementRef) {

  }

  GetParentPanel() {
    // Step up the dom to find the next object that is the parent and a panel (If any)
    let stepping = true;
    let e = this.element.nativeElement;
    let override = 0;
    while (stepping) {
      e = e.parentElement;
      console.log('e:', e);
      if (e) {
        if (e instanceof TESTPanelComponent) {
          stepping = false;
          this.ParentPanel = e;
          console.log('parent panel set to : ' , this.ParentPanel);
        }
      } else {
        stepping = false;
        console.log('no parent');
      }
      override ++;
      if (override >= 1000) { console.log('override. Doesnt exist.'); stepping = false; }
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the best way to go about this. Why not have the parent pass down to its child whether it's disabled?

Comment: via inputs? I was trying to avoid adding all of the extra tags to the elements. This way I could have 1 service call on the top parent that basically gives permission to a specific panel, once that is done.. All of the control that are children could change to the correct state. (Or show the correct items based on the permission level) Technically I could do @Input() all the way down and just pass the role, but it seems like a lot of extra work instead of a few well placed functions.

Comment: If you want to avoid inputs, how about each panel subscribes to an injected service, which updates them on whether the parent has changed?

Comment: This looks shorter, but using `nativeElement` comes with some risk. And won't work if you ever want to use server side rendering. Plus with the new renderer coming out soon ... You may at least want to put an `if` around the `let e` to ensure that `nativeElement` is not null.

Comment: I like the service idea, Only issue I have is.. I still have no way of knowing which panel is a child or parent. What I am currently creating is a "Control Lib" to be used in my other projects. So the more generic the better. I can't create a bunch of custom arrays such as "SuperRoleControls" and "CustomerControls" unfortunately. If I had the panels subscrive to a service, I'm not sure what to do after that. I'd have to have an input or something that defines a specific panel as a parent to a subset of controls somehow.

Comment: For components I intend to reuse in other projects I usually just accept that they will require inputs. Do you already have a lot of inputs, that adding one more is an issue? Maybe you can pass an object instead of many inputs?

Comment: Actually yeah, I could just use 1 input as the "parent" element and pass the parent into each child, then oninit the child can look at the parent and see what's what and set itself up for whats needed. Thanks for the assist.